# How do I deal with Spaces in the $PSScriptRoot path in powershell

Tags: java, powershell, path, spaces

I am trying to write a powershell script that will Install Java using an Installcfg.cfg file.  I would like it to be able to run no matter where the script is executed.  It works fine when there are no spaces in any of the file paths however when I run it from another location I get the following error:

There are errors in the following switches:
"INSTALLCFG='C:\Program";"Files";"(x86\DesktopCentral_Agent\swrepository\1\swuploades\Java";"8";"Update";"25\InstallCFG.cfg'";.

Powershell does not appear to be passing the file paths as I want them.

The script is as follows:

```
#Determine the Architecture
$Arch = (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).OSArchitecture

#Make sure no browsers are running
kill -processname iexplore, chrome, firefox

#Install based on Architecture
if ($Arch -eq "64-bit")
    {
    Start-Process jre-8u25-windows-x64.exe -wait -args "INSTALLCFG=$PSScriptRoot\InstallCFG.cfg /L c:\temp\java64.txt"
    Start-Process jre-8u25-windows-i586.exe -wait -args "INSTALLCFG=$PSScriptRoot\InstallCFG.cfg /L c:\temp\java32.txt"
    }

else 
    {
    Start-Process jre-8u25-windows-i586.exe -args "INSTALLCFG=$PSScriptRoot\InstallCFG.cfg /L c:\temp\java32.txt"
    }
```

I have tried various ways of including quotes in the arguments and even creating the arguments as a variable.  I do not want to hard-code the location because I want the file to run from anywhere.

I am basically trying to run the following command from a batch file in powershell:

```
"%~dp0jre-8u25-windows-x64.exe" INSTALLCFG="%~dp0InstallCFG.cfg" /L c:\temp\log.txt
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The escape character is backtick. You should be able to write something like

```
"INSTALLCFG=`"$PSScriptRoot\InstallCFG.cfg`" /L c:\temp\java64.txt"
```

for the args argument.